# How to separate user datas by schemas (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, database-schema

I'm new in Ruby on Rails world.  I want to create new schema for each user after his registration to the system. 
I want something like this after registration(in registration controller):
- create a new schema for a user 
- create all need tables in the schema 
So how can I realize it?